# Beamer how to change color of infolines and frame title

Tags: beamer, color, themes

How could I change the color of color of infolines and frame title in beamer. I am using this now

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usecolortheme[named=Brown]{structure}
```

I need to change the color from red to brown. `[named=Brown]` doesn't work for `\useoutertheme{infolines}`. This is my current output. I also need to change the background of frame title (mouse pointer)

[image]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Redefine the `frametitle`, `section in head/foot`, `author in head/foot colors`, and `date in head/foot` colors:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=Brown,bg=Brown!20}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=Brown}
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg=Brown}
\setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{fg=Brown}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A test frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same could have been achieved with:

```
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{bg=Brown}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=Brown,bg=Brown!20}
```