# Changing font color in headline

Tags: beamer, sectioning, color

I am wondering how can I change the font color in the headline of my presentation?

I saw [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133820/beamer-how-to-change-color-of-infolines-and-frame-title) how to change the color of the bar but not the actual font.

Original code:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
 \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
 \useinnertheme{rectangles}
 \useoutertheme{infolines}

 \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=Brown,bg=Brown!20}
 \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=Brown}
 \setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg=Brown}
 \setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{fg=Brown}

 \begin{document}

 \section{Font to be changed in the headline}
 \begin{frame}
 \frametitle{A test frame}
 \end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

Edit: After the answer, the following doesn't seem to work for me

```
 \documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
 \mode<presentation>
 {
 \usetheme{AnnArbor}
 \setbeamercovered{transparent}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
   \usecolortheme{spruce}
 }

  \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=White}


 \begin{document}

 \section{Font to be changed in the headline}
 \begin{frame}
 \frametitle{A test frame}
 \end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

I would like to keep the theme as it is and I would only like to change the font of the headline to be white, otherwise it's unreadable.

Thanks.

Comment: I added the original code that you changed in the edit (otherwise, the first part of my answer wouldn't make sense and other readers might get confused). I hope it's OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `fg` (foreground) specification for the appropriate color templates; for example:

```
 \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=Brown,fg=red}
 \setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{bg=gray!30,fg=black}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=Brown,bg=Brown!20}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=Brown,fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{bg=gray!30,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg=Brown}
\setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{fg=Brown}

\begin{document}

\section{Font changed in the headline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A test frame}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Font changed in the headline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A test frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Font changed in the headline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A test frame}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Font changed in the headline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A test frame}
\end{frame}
 
\end{document}
```

The resulting headline:

[image]

### Update

After the edit to the question, this

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
 \mode<presentation>
 {
 \usetheme{AnnArbor}
 \setbeamercovered{transparent}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
   \usecolortheme{spruce}
 }

  \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=White}


 \begin{document}

 \section{Font to be changed in the headline}
 \begin{frame}
 \frametitle{A test frame}
 \end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: Hi Gonzalo Medina, thanks for the quick reply. It does not work for me

Comment: @tom your comment is useless. Please add to your question a simple, yet complete document (like the one in my answer) showing the problem mentioned.

Comment: Your are totally right. Please see above I am editing the question. thanks again

Comment: @tom please see my updated answer. With your code I get the desired result (see image attached at the bottom). If you don't get this with the exact code you posted, perhaps you are using outdated packages?

Comment: it works now. It was a clash with the hyperref package. thank you very much for the answers