# Beamer: change header background color

Tags: beamer, color, backgrounds, beamer-metropolis

I have decided to switch from Powerpoint to Beamer, and for my first presentation I'd like to use the [metropolis theme](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/metropolis-beamer-theme/qzyvdhrntfmr#.WNYrcRjpORs), and the same colors as in this goggle slide template:

[image: Google slides theme].

I tried to do some research about it, the closest answers I found are the question [Beamer how to change color of infolines and frame title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133820/beamer-how-to-change-color-of-infolines-and-frame-title) and the [beamer appearance cheat sheet](http://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~masson/latex/Beamer-appearance-cheat-sheet.pdf). I tried this code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\definecolor{bluegreen}{rgb}{3, 166, 155}
\definecolor{pitchblack}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{lightbeige}{rgb}{255, 251, 241}
\definecolor{mediumgray}{rgb}{183, 183, 183}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=pitchblack}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=lightbeige}
\setbeamercolor{headline}{bg=bluegreen, fg=mediumgray}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{The title}
    Lorem ipsum...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I does everything I want, except that the title bar's background color is lightbeige:

[image: everything's fine, except the title bar background color]

What did I do wrong? Or what argument should I pass to `\setbeamercolor` to get it right? Thanks in advance :-).

Comment: Link to [the question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133820/beamer-how-to-change-color-of-infolines-and-frame-title)  
Link to [metropolis](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/metropolis-beamer-theme/qzyvdhrntfmr#.WNYrcRjpORs)  
Link to the "[cheat sheet](http://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~masson/latex/Beamer-appearance-cheat-sheet.pdf)"

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  You should set the background of the frametitle for this: `\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=lightbeige}`

Comment: Incidentally, on my installation of texlive, the theme name has to be lower case: `\usetheme{metropolis}`

Comment: Indeed, "metropolis" is all lowercase n my beamer folder. It was just a typo. I edit my MWE to correct it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Andrew Swann already said in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360307/beamer-change-header-background-color/360349#comment888071_360307), you want to modify the frametitle colour and not the headline colour (as far as I can see, the `metropolis` theme does not have a headline).

The next problem is that you need `RGB` and not `rgb` in the colour definition - `rgb` would take values between 0 and 1.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\definecolor{bluegreen}{RGB}{3, 166, 155}
\definecolor{pitchblack}{RGB}{0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{lightbeige}{RGB}{255, 251, 241}
\definecolor{mediumgray}{RGB}{183, 183, 183}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=pitchblack}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=lightbeige}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=bluegreen, fg=mediumgray}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{The title}
    Lorem ipsum...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]